# Sculpin custom content type is not generating

Tags: php, sculpin

I'm building a [Sculpin](https://sculpin.io/) website, and I've added a custom content type called people:

```
sculpin_content_types:
    posts:
        layout: post_type
        permalink: blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug_title/
    people:
        layout: person_type
        permalink: who/:basename/
        singular_name: person
```

The content for people is found in the `source/_people` folder.
Based on [the documentation](https://sculpin.io/documentation/content-types/custom-types/) I would expect the result of the *generate* command to create the folder `output_dev/who` containing one [person] folder for each [person.md] that was in the _people folder.

What actually happens is that there is a folder `output_dev/_people`, as if the content type wasn't defined.

But when I add *--watch* to the *generate* command and make changes to the `people.md` files in the source, sculpin generates the correct files in the path `output_dev/who/personA/index.html`.

Why isn't the custom content type being generated on first run?

**UPDATE**

Part of the problem has to do with the fact that I'm trying to cross-reference the two types of posts. A *post* has a property *author* that points to a *person*. On the generated page for a person I want to display a list of all posts by that person, so I assumed we could add `use: [posts]` to the definition:

These are the contents of a file called `source/_people/ramon.md`

```
---

slug: ramon
fullname: Ramon de la Fuente
avatar: ramon.png

use: [posts]

---

Lorem ipsum.
```

**important:** Removing `use: [posts]` makes it work like expected. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by the creator of Sculpin, and should no longer exist.

https://github.com/sculpin/sculpin/pull/193